# Remoting plugin for cakephp 2.0 and flex

Tags: php, apache-flex, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a website written in cakephp 1.2 and I'm updating it to cakephp 2.0. This website has a flex front end and I'm using **CpAmf** plugin for that purpose. It seems like CpAmf plugin **has no support with cakephp 2.0 yet**. Can anyone recommend me a good remoting plugin for cakephp 2.0 and flex?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know of anything out there that supports Cake 2.0+, this might be a really good starting point: http://code.google.com/p/flexiblecake/

At first glance, it seems rather simple to build upon.